# KeyError: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred

Tags: python, pandas

I have this error :

```
    KeyError: 'id_cont'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    <ipython-input-11-4604edb9a0b7> in generateID(self, outputMode, data_df)
         84 
         85         if outputMode.getModeCB() == CONST_MODE_CONT:
    ---> 86             data_df['id_cont'] = data_df.apply(lambda row:row['product_name']+'-'+row['hour_local'],axis=1)
         87             #data_df['id_cont'] = data_df.apply(lambda row:row['equipement']+'-'+row['product_name']+'-'+row['hour_shift'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),axis=1)
         88         else:

    /dataiku/dss_data/code-envs/python/Python3_6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
       2936         else:
       2937             # set column
    -> 2938             self._set_item(key, value)
       2939 
       2940     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):


    ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 149, placement implies 1
```

Adding this line brings up this error, I think that it's a data type problem :

`data_df['id_cont'] = data_df.apply(lambda row:row['product_name']+'-'+row['hour_shift'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),axis=1)`

`hour_shift` is a datetime and `product_name`, `equipment` are object.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: I can't put the entire log, here is an exerpt. I don't have any idea of how to solve my problem, if you have an idea I am interested thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this offers very little context. Please read these threads to learn how to create a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you're getting this error is because the `data_df` is an empty dataframe due to no rows satisfy the condition `data_df['hour_local'].isin(target_hours)`, causing all `hour_shift` column values to be `NaT`, making all rows to be dropped at `data_df = data_df.dropna(subset=['hour_shift'])`. You can test this by using the sample data that has `hour_local` values that satisfy the condition vs that doesn't

Satisfy condition:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.DataFrame({'local_time': [datetime.strptime("08:30:00",'%H:%M:%S'), datetime.strptime("08:24:00",'%H:%M:%S')], 'product_name': ['A', 'B']})
delta = timedelta(minutes=5)

# Start time
start_time = datetime.strptime("08:20:00",'%H:%M:%S')
cur_time = start_time
target_hours = []
while cur_time.date() <= start_time.date():
    target_hours.append(cur_time.time())
    cur_time += delta

data_df['hour_local'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df["local_time"].astype(str)).dt.time
data_df = data_df.drop(columns=['hour_shift'], errors='ignore')
data_df.loc[data_df['hour_local'].isin(target_hours),'hour_shift'] = data_df['local_time']
data_df = data_df.sort_values(by=['local_time'])
data_df['hour_shift'] = data_df['hour_shift'].ffill()
data_df = data_df.dropna(subset=['hour_shift'])
# This will print dataframe with one row
print(data_df)
data_df['id_cont'] = data_df.apply(lambda row:row['product_name']+'- '+row['hour_shift'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),axis=1) 
print(data_df)
```

Not satisfy condition:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
import pandas as pd

# NOTE: no data satisfy the below condition
data_df = pd.DataFrame({'local_time': [datetime.strptime("08:31:00",'%H:%M:%S'), datetime.strptime("08:24:00",'%H:%M:%S')], 'product_name': ['A', 'B']})
delta = timedelta(minutes=5)

# Start time
start_time = datetime.strptime("08:20:00",'%H:%M:%S')
cur_time = start_time
target_hours = []
while cur_time.date() <= start_time.date():
    target_hours.append(cur_time.time())
    cur_time += delta

data_df['hour_local'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df["local_time"].astype(str)).dt.time
data_df = data_df.drop(columns=['hour_shift'], errors='ignore')
data_df.loc[data_df['hour_local'].isin(target_hours),'hour_shift'] = data_df['local_time']
data_df = data_df.sort_values(by=['local_time'])
data_df['hour_shift'] = data_df['hour_shift'].ffill()
data_df = data_df.dropna(subset=['hour_shift'])
# This will print empty dataframe
print(data_df)
data_df['id_cont'] = data_df.apply(lambda row:row['product_name']+'- '+row['hour_shift'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),axis=1)
```

One way I think you can avoid this error is the add a check to only run the apply line if the dataframe is not empty

```
if len(data_df):
    data_df['id_cont'] = data_df.apply(lambda row:row['product_name']+'- '+row['hour_shift'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),axis=1) 
    print(data_df)
```